# Change Logo when scroll with fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When scroll down I want to change logo `img`. I writing small code [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9rtf1em)

I think my code is working correctly, I tried, but couldn't understand how to add `fadein` and `fadeout` effect.

P.S. Maybe you can show me same another function, because at same website I see where this work only with css.

```
<header style="position: fixed; margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; z-index: 999;">
    <div class="logo fleft"> <a href="/" id="logo-img">
            <img src="https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo11w.png" title="GeoConsul.Gov.Ge - Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Georgia" />
          </a>
    </div>
</header>
```

```css
.logo img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```js
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 114) {
            // $('#logo-img img').fadeOut('slow');
            $('#logo-img img')
                .css({
                'width': '275px',
                'height': '95px',
                'padding-top': '4px'
            })
                .attr('src', 'https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo1w.png');
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 114) {
            // $('#logo-img img').fadeIn('fast');
            $('#logo-img img')
                .css({
                'width': '538px',
                'height': '190px',
                'padding-top': '0px'
            })
                .attr('src', 'https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Note the use of the `css3 transition` property. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/u96c2ggb/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.logo img{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease-in
}
```

Comment: Thx, but have we any ideas? Because with addClass is not good I think

Answer (score 0):

Add a style tag like this

```
<style>.transition{ opacity: 0.5; transition: opacity 2.0s}</style>
```

and then do a jQuery addClass/removeClass with class "transition" and it will fade in fade out.

You can change the opacity to determine how much it fades.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the URL using a javascript (or jQuery) DOM property alteration such that when the window is a certain offset from the top the URL for the image changes.